# What does `log2_work` in Bitcoin Core's output mean?

Tags: proof-of-work

I have a question.
Does the "log2_work" finally is a "proof de work" ? :)

Do you know what does it mean ?

Answer (score 2):

It is the 2-logarithm of the expected number of block header hash attempts were necessary the build the chain up to that point.

For example, for block *768557*, the `log2_work` is 93.909086. This means that roughly *2<sup>93.909086</sup> = 1.85973 ⨉ 10<sup>28</sup>* block hash attempts (each roughly a double-SHA256 operation) have been attempted.